# Multiple regex patterns vs. one regex with conditions

Tags: regex

I'm using pseudocode in this this question because it is not about the performance of a specific regex implementation, but rather about the algorithmic aspect of matching a regex pattern.

I'm building a URL matcher that matches any of a set of patterns. It can be done like this:

```
patterns = ["^foo", "bar$", "poi"]

url = ...

success = any(p.match(url) for p in patterns)
```

but I can also do this:

```
pattern = "^foo|bar$|poi"

url = ...

success = p.match(url)
```

My question is, theoretically, can a regex matcher do approach 2 faster than approach 1 in some clever way? (And practically, are real regex engines usually implemented like so?)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect, in general, the alternation version `^foo|bar$|poi` to outperform the version where you iterate over separate patterns and build a separate regex to each condition.  The reason for this is that everytime you invoke `match` from your Python script, you are forcing the interpreter to setup a new run with the regex engine.  There must be some kind of overhead to that, and the alternation avoids doing this all but one time.  On top of this, I expect that Python's regex engine is optimized to handle alternations efficiently.

Comment: Assuming it's a NFA-type regex engine (.NET, PHP, Ruby, Perl, Python, etc.), if the regex were `"^foo|bar$|poi"`, wouldn't it exhaust all possibilities with `"foo"` before looking at `"bar$"` then exhaust all possibilities with `"bar$"` before looking at `"poi"`? If so, I can't see why there would be much of a difference between doing that and performing (up to) three separate searches.

Comment: I've posted a benchmark to bolster my suspicion....Hey, wait a minute...

Comment: @CarySwoveland _Suspension_ ?  I mean, my answer may not be perfect, but...

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extended comment than answer. I thought it might be interesting to show the results of an simple benchmark, albeit one that is extremely limited. The following is written in Ruby but I expect non-Rubyists will be able to follow what I am doing.

First I'll generate some test data.

```
words = ["foo", "bar", "poi", "cat", "dog"] 
arr = 100_000.times.map { words.sample(3).join(' ') })
  #=> ["bar foo dog", "foo cat poi", "poi dog bar", "dog bar cat",
  #    "bar foo poi",...
```

As you see each element (string) of `arr` is generated by randomly selecting 3 elements from the array `words` and forming them into a string.

Now create the two methods to be compared.

```
def m1(arr)
  r = /^foo|bar$|poi/
  arr.each { |s| s.match r }
end
```

```
def m3(arr)
  a = [/^foo/, /bar$/, /poi/]
  arr.each { |s| a.find { |r| s.match r } }
end
```

`m1` uses 1 regex with an alternation. `m3` uses 3 regexes, terminating (if and) as soon as there is match.

I've used a Ruby gem called `fruity` to do the benchmark.

```
require 'fruity'

compare(
  regex1: -> { m1(arr) },
  regex3: -> { m3(arr) }
)
```

The results speak for themselves.

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 4 seconds.
regex1 is faster than regex3 by 2.3x ± 0.01
```